# webservice shows parser error

Tags: c#, web-services

i am new to .net and i have to create a webservice for connecting with android.i got a simple example code and i put it in a mew webservice application and run it in debug mode.but it shows the following  error in firefox.pls help to correct it.

Service1.asmx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace HelloAndroid
{
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://sample.com/")]
    public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        [WebMethod]
        public string SayHello()
        {
            return "Hello, Android from .NET";
        }
    }
}
```

error

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Parser Error
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Could not create type 'WebService1.Service1'.

Source Error:


Line 1:  <%@ WebService Language="C#" CodeBehind="Service1.asmx.cs" Class="WebService1.Service1" %>


Source File: /Service1.asmx    Line: 1

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.6387; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.6387
```

Comment: Your service isn't called `WebService1.Service1`, it's called `HelloAndroid.Service1`. Please show some research effort. :) Also, if you're new and trying to learn web services in .NET, skip ASMX and start with WCF.

Answer (score 0):

You've probably changed the namespace from `WebService1` to `HelloAndroid` in `Service1.asmx.cs`. You need to update `Service1.asmx` file as well.